# bootstrap modal not clear validation after open new modal to Add New Server?

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

I work on blazor app with .NET core 7 . I face issue validation not reset or removed after open new modal .

Issue display on step 5 when open New Bootstrap Modal

so my scenario as below for details by steps :

1. I click button add New server so bootstrap modal opened and loaded .
2. I will leave server name empty then click button submit .
3. I will get message error validation server name is empty .
4. I will close bootstrap modal to add new server .
5. After I open bootstrap modal again to add new server so issue display so issue validation still exist**

**so How to reset validation when open new modal bootstrap to add New Server ?**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="margin-right:100px;">
                    Add New Server
            
                </h5>
        <button type="button" style="background-color: white !important;" data-bs-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            </div>
            <EditForm Model="@sn" OnValidSubmit="submit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
                <ValidationSummary style="color:red"></ValidationSummary>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="p-2 w-100 bd-highlight">
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">Server Name</label>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@sn.Server_Name" />
                                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => sn.Server_Name)" style="color:red"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Create
                                </button>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </EditForm>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

blazor component

```cs
@code
{
    private ServerNames sn = new ServerNames();
}
```

my modal servers

```cs
public class ServerNames
{
    [Key]
    public int ServerID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Server name is required")]
    public string Server_Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from the code how you are showing and hiding the Bootstrap modal, but you're are almost certainly just showing it or hiding it.  You aren't resetting your edit object or the edit context.

Here's a demo where I use Razor logic to show and hide the modal.  In this context the components within the modal are destroyed when the modal is hidden and created when the modal is shown.

Note this a very basic implementation missing a lot of logic that should be implemented in an edit form.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div>
    <button disabled="@_showDialog" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=AddServer >Add Server</button>
</div>

@if (_showDialog)
{
    <div class="modal show modal-background" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Editor</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <EditForm Model="@sn" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                        <ValidationSummary style="color:red"></ValidationSummary>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                                <div class="p-2 w-100 bd-highlight">

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">Server Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@sn.Server_Name" />
                                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => sn.Server_Name)" style="color:red"></ValidationMessage>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="m-2 text-end">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=Exit>Exit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<style>
    .modal-background {
        display: block;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }
</style>

@code {
    private bool _showDialog; 
    private ServerNames sn = new();

    private void AddServer()
    {
        sn = new();
        _showDialog = true;
    }

    private void Exit()
    {
        _showDialog = false;
    }

    private Task Submit()
    {
        _showDialog = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class ServerNames
    {
        [Key] public int ServerID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Server name is required")]
        public string? Server_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Take a look at some of the Blazor dialog implementations.  Search "Blazor Modal Dialog".